# Do we still need to use "having trouble with this link/button" copiable URLs in emails?

Tags: email, html-email, email-client

Every here and there we see an email with a cool CTA button or a handy link in the middle of the copy, but shortly after it there's the full URL (usually ugly), in case "you have trouble clicking the link above".

Is that still a thing nowadays?
Are there (which ones?) email clients that completely disable HTML links, forcing the user to copy and paste the said URL in their browser?

Example:

```
<p>Bla bla email copy</p>
<a href="http://example.com" style="look-like-button">Click here!</a>
<em>(if you have trouble with this button, copy and paste this URL: http://example.com)</em>
```

> PS: I'm not talking about `text/plain` emails here, obviously they'll have their own way to present URLs :)

Comment: does it hurt you so hard? what is the problem of letting the whole link at e-mail

Comment: I didn't ask if they are bad. I asked if they're needed. Why would you leave something not needed (and usually ugly) in the way of your good copy and layout?

Comment: the answer is 50/50 and opinion based. I tend not to keep it as there are devices that load images (apart from Outlook). Look at how much of your users are using outlook, it might give you idea how much people (kinda) need the view online URL.

Comment: Thanks @Syfer! But I was actually referring to `<a>` tags that you have to "hard-code" the URL in the text. I included an example by editing the question, now.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is more of a business question, usually for a business is really important that the user get the information it's requesting. May it be a password recovery, registration link or any other that may have an impact on active users at the system. Those emails are likely to be automated and the user can't ask for help if the link doesn't work.

Regarding the email clients, that goes beyond it, there are some anti spam/virus like MailScanner that can replace/break a hidden link if it finds that maybe harmful or try to obfuscate the real link. (Usually when not proper configured or when it finds a real phishing etc...)

But like I said, how important is to your business,that this user can access the right link? (via button, hard code link or whatever)

Hope that helps! =]